# Dynamics CRM 2011 - What is the best way to ensure a custom entity cannot be updated or deleted?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a custom entity that once created I do not want it updated or deleted. Is a plugin the best way to ensure that or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look in my update, there is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is you apply security roles to this custom entity. Create a role only with read action and apply to your users or team.

**EDIT:**

I remember another option, the "Read Optimized Forms". Take a look with a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/03/22/read-optimized-forms.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Pedro, a second question. I have an entity that I only want created though a plugin, Is there a good way to make sure that you can't manually create it?

Comment: Yes in security you have the action Create if you disabled this action no one can create a record for this entity. Take a look in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334717.aspx)

Comment: They need to be able to create it through the plugin. I would think that would keep them from creating it at all.

Comment: @Gary, consider creating a new question.  It'll be much more searchable for other developers looking to solve the same issue.

Comment: I agree with @Daryl, please make another post.

Comment: @PedroAzevedo, you are rocking up the Stack Overflow Points.  Keep it up.

Comment: Hi @Daryl thanks for your words. More important that the points is the knowledge with all answers\questions of community.

Comment: @PerdoAzevedo, My favorite times are when I search Stack Overflow for an answer, only to find that I gave the answer a year earlier.